# Expiration Alert Email Workflow SPD2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

Attached is a screen grab of my workflow. I'm attempting to email a user a notification when the End Date (calculated column[=Created+365]) is equal to 'Today' which means the document has expired. To test out the workflow I set a specific time and date for 'Today'. The workflow isn't comparing End Date to Today. As soon as the WF is initiated, it sends the alert email. Which means this WF is not functioning correctly, it completes upon initiation. Please provide a step-by-step explanation. Thank you

[image: Workflow Screen Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use “set workflow variable” action, you can directly use “Current date” in the “If any value equals value” condition as below:
[image]

Besides, if you want to give an email alert when the document expires, you can use “pause until date” action to pause the workflow until end date and send email.
[image]

Then in the workflow settings, select “start workflow automatically when an item is created” in start options section:

[image]